# CSS styles overlay

Tags: css

I have a modal window, which i dinamically load to the client web site.
That modal contains some css styles. In some cases my form is breaks.
For example i have input with class

```
.my_btn {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2f889a !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    border-radius: 0.3em !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    ...
}
```

which apply my styles, but client site can contain style looks like:

```
input[type="submit"]{...}
```

whick rewrites my css. 
I have some assumptions how can i solve this problem, but they are so bulky and not universal. Can you help me?
How can i foresee all possible problems,

Comment: There's not enough code here to diagnose your issue.

Comment: ohh god so much spell mistakes in your quesiton

Comment: I will be glad if you correct them.

Comment: Just use more specific CSS rules.

Comment: Can you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the problem with other CSS on the page common approach is to make *your* rules more specific. Make sure you are familiar with [CSS Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) - those rules dictate what CSS is applied and in what order.

The simplest way to add some weight to your CSS declarations is to describe parent hierarchy of your modal elements. It will depend of HTML structure of your modal popaup, but you can get the idea. Instead of just `.my_btn` you should write something like

```
.modal-container .modal-body .modal-content .my_btn {
    /* ... */
}
```

Such rule will be much more bullet proof against other page CSS.

There are other approaches, for example following strict CSS writing rules, like [BEM](https://en.bem.info/). In better future we will use [WebComponents](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/), so the style conflicts will not be an issue anymore.

Comment: Thank you, i guess this can help me.